# Embed browsers components

Tags: browser, embed

Is there an application that lets you pack it with a bunch of html files and it will render them? Basically, I want an app that all it does is that it has an embedded browser, and I can pack it with my files. Is there such thing?
It would be nice if it was cross-platform or offered additional APIs.

My end goal is I wanna build an app that produces html and then compiles it and gives it to the user.
One solution is to use Opera Widgets, my app can build the html files, and then pack it as a desktop widget. But that requires user to have Opera installed. It would be nice if there was an embedded browser solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/). It is basically a JS-heavy application packed in a platfrom-independent package. Also includes a WebKit-compatible browser.

May be less or more than what you need.